# How to download ebook form Kindle to my PC?

Tags: ubuntu, ebook, kindle

I want to be able to read offline the ebook that I've bought from Amazon store. So I need to be able to download the ebook. I don't have a kindle reader (tablet) and don't like to be plugged into Amazon's crapware to read my ebook. So how can I download the ebook on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You can read with any web browser at https://read.amazon.com/

If you wanted to download it you'd need a Windows PC since that's the only desktop OS they offer dedicated reader software for.

Comment: Supposedly you can even read it offline this way, but I haven't been able to make it work offline (even on Windows, where I was forced to use their app instead).

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful application called [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), available for all platforms. Calibre allows you to import books from all e-book readers, not just Amazon's, to read them and keep them ordered, to convert from one format to another and into pdf, to sync between your readers and your pc. Also, it gives you a convenient way to deal with DRMs, see [here](http://tips4linux.com/remove-drm-from-amazon-kindles-ebooks-using-linux/).

Comment: I tried to use the link but don't know how to save the booked that I've bought to my harddrive. So got stocked before doing anything to remove DRM.

Comment: @hnns You must install Calibre first. Have you done that?

Comment: @hnns Are you having problems because you do not own a kindle? If so, apologies, I had not understood your question. Still, you solve this problem with Calibre. You must install **both** Kindle for PC **and** Calibre. You download the book you just bought to your Kindle for pc, then, following instructions here, http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=152823, you can move books between Calibre and Kindle for pc (often called K4PC).

Comment: Marius, I don't have Windows either. Is there any chance that I can download the kindle book to my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: @hnns LOL, neither do I, I am writing this from Linux myself. Just do *sudo apt-get install calibre*

Comment: Sorry I got confused. You said one needs both K4PC AND Calibre. However K4PC is available only for Windows, which I don't have. So would you please complete your answer regarding my situation?

Comment: @hnns Read here, http://lifehacker.com/5406505/run-kindle-for-pc-in-linux-with-wine